# SOAP security: password param good enough?

Tags: java, spring, security, soap, cxf

I've got 2 backends that need to share information between them using SOAP services across the Internet. Theses services are designed to be only used between these 2 backends so I need to secure them.

I've been reading about securing SOAP APIs but in this instance wouldn't a 'password' param in each method of the API be enough? The password would be hardcoded in each backend and verified at each call against the hardcoded one.

There are 3 methods total so implementation would be easy enough. Also, both points are server sided (client calls one point of the backend, not the SOAP API) so I guess hardcoding the password isn't that terrible.

Does this implementation pose any security risks? Would it be worth it to do it any other way?

Server backend is Spring + CXF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A way to implement this is using [Public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). This allows you to share a public key with the other side to encrypt the messages send. The message can then be decrypted with the private key. more in the wiki entry above.

[java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/step2.html)

[Tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-asymmetric-cryptography-example/)

All these links on the subject where done with a quick google search so you should be easly be able to find more examples on this subject by googling:

> java public key encryption tutorial